# Установка RLdev под Linux (OCaml)

Tags: ocaml

При сборке инструментов [RLdev](http://dev.haeleth.net/rldev.shtml) вылетает ошибка:

```
$ ./configure && omake
........
File "pa_matches.ml", line 24, characters 2-6:
Parse error: Deprecated syntax, the grammar module is expected
Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: camlp4 pa_o.cmo pa_op.cmo pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo pr_dump.cmo 'pa_matches.ml' > /home/.../tmp/ocamlpp4e8738

*** omake error:
   File rlc/OMakefile: lines 26:4-27:88
   command terminated with code 2: ocamlc -c -pp 'camlp4 pa_o.cmo pa_op.cmo pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo pr_dump.cmo' -I /usr/lib/ocaml/camlp4 gramlib.cma pa_matches.ml -o pa_matches.cmo
```

В файле `pa_matches.ml` нет ничего, кроме нескольких строчек кода:

```
Строка 22: open Pcaml
Строка 23: EXTEND
Строка 24:   expr: LEVEL "expr1"
Строка 25:     [[ v = expr; "matches"; p = patt -> <:expr< match $v$ with [ $p$ -> True | _ -> False ] >> ]];
Строка 26: END
```

В файле `INSTALL` указана версия OCaml 3.09, но у меня установлена 4.01.

Answer (score 1):

перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688394/4827341), данного автору:

*OCaml 3.09* несовместим с *OCaml 4.01*. это в особенности относится к *camlp4*. с *OCaml 3.10* появилась новая, без обратной совместимости, версия  *camlp4*.

это вероятная причина, почему `pa_matches.ml` не компилируется: требуется старый *camlp4*.